# How to start private conversation in a multiple users channel (botframework)?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot that is running in a multiple users channel (Slack). The bot reacts on a trigger in the channel. How can I respond to the user, who called the bot, in a private conversation with the user?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a way for the bot to only respond to the user calling on the bot, then you could try to make use of Slack's [ephemeral message type as documented here.](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command)

From the documentation:

> By default, the response messages sent to commands will only be
>   visible to the user that issued the command (we call these "ephemeral"
>   messages). ... Setting  response_type  to  ephemeral  is the same as
>   not including the response type at all, and the response message will
>   be visible only to the user that issued the command.

Basically, in a group channel, ephemeral messages are only sent to the user issuing the command instead of being broadcast to the group.

In your bot's code, you then just need to make use of the C# bot builder's [custom channel message capability](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html#customslackmessages) to alter the `channelData` field of the outgoing message.

For example:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "locale": "en-Us",
    "channelId":"slack",
    "conversation": { "id":"123123123123", "topic":"awesome chat" },
    "from": { "id":"12345", "name":"My Bot"},
    "recipient": { "id":"67890", "name":"Joe Doe"},
    "channelData": {
        "response_type": "ephemeral",
        "text": "This is some message.",
        "attachments": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Where `channelData` follows the [Slack Message formatting guidelines.](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages#composing_messages)

If you are looking for the ability for your bot to break off into a completely new 1:1 conversation with the user, [maybe take a look at the documentation for Starting Conversations](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#conversation) and the `CreateDirectConversation()` method.